# Unexpected T_String

Tags: php

```
unset($item_row);
$item_row = array();
if ($row[1] == "BCP-Prod1"){
    $row[1] = "BCP-Product1";
    $item_row['nid'] = 71;
    $item_row['title'] = 'Product1 - This is the title';
} elseif ($row[1] == "BCP-SILLYNECK"){
    $row[1] = "BCP-Prod2";
    $item_row['nid'] = 77;
    $item_row['title'] = 'Products2 - This is the title for 2';
}
```

The error I am getting is:

> Parse error:  parse error, unexpected
>   T_STRING in import_orders.php on line
>   89

Line 89 is `$item_row['nid'] = 71;`  I must be looking over something cause I am not seeing what is causing this?

Comment: Sounds like a missing semicolon ( ; ) on a previous line somewhere. I don't see it here in this code.

Comment: everything is correct. Are you sure you are looking at the right piece of code? Better paste it on pastebin, to have a complete view.

Comment: I'll bet that you have a single quote `'` that's not closed before that line (considering that's the first single-quote in the block you posted).  Either post more of the file (before the `unset` line), or use a syntax-highlighting editor to view the file...

Comment: @ircmaxell, Totally agree. In the shop next door they have processors more powerful than the supercomputers of 30 years ago, and people are still coding in simple text editors, when there are such great works for developers like NetBeans or Eclipse PDT, which highlight the errors as you type.

Comment: Heck even most text editors do syntax highlighting (`vim` for example).  You don't *need* a full blown IDE to get the benefits (although I agree for project level work it's hard to beat an IDE)...

Comment: @ircmaxell - totally agreed!!!

Comment: @ircmaxell  That was the problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because you have an unclosed single quote (`'`) somewhere before that line.

Try to use a syntax-highlighting editor from now on.  It'll help with debugging since this kind of error will be immediately apparent...